# java.sql.SQLException: Too many connections + Spring IBatis

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, ibatis, spring-jdbc

I am running with the issue `java.sql.SQLException: Too many connections`.

Platform:
`Tomcat server, Java Spring, iBatis and MySQL Amazon Instance`

Below is my `JDBC` configuration:

```
app.jbdc.initialSize=10
app.jbdc.maxActive=200
app.jdbc.maxWait =1000
app.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis =500
app.jdbc.validationQuery=select 1
app.jdbc.testOnBorrow=true
app.jdbc.removeAbandoned=true
app.jdbc.removeAbandonedTimeout=30
```

Below is Error stack:

```
java.sql.SQLException
MESSAGE: Too many connections
STACKTRACE:

java.sql.SQLException: Too many connections
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2851)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:753)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3562)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1154)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:1818)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:405)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:268)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:294)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:840)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor28.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$3.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:757)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:281)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:113)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.execution.SqlExecutor.prepareStatement(SqlExecutor.java:494)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.execution.SqlExecutor.executeUpdate(SqlExecutor.java:76)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.GeneralStatement.sqlExecuteUpdate(GeneralStatement.java:200)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.GeneralStatement.executeUpdate(GeneralStatement.java:78)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.insert(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:447)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.insert(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:82)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate$8.doInSqlMapClient(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:366)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:200)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.insert(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:364)
    at com.wo.user.dao.UserDaoImpl.insertUser(UserDaoImpl.java:26)
    at com.wo.user.service.UserServiceImpl.insertUser(UserServiceImpl.java:89)
    at com.wo.version2.controller.UserControllerV2.registerUser2(UserControllerV2.java:187)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor46.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:421)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:774)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:202)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:156)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1822)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Is there anything we can control the maximum active thread? What can be done in this situation?

**Assumption: Spring iBatis is taking care of the connection close and open**

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you tell us what connection pooling library you use? Also could you post an example of your iBatis usage OR just confirm that you are not opening sessions manually?

Comment: Yes I am not using any third party library for pooling. Also not opening sessions manually.. I just used `org.springframework.orm.ibatis.support.SqlMapClientDaoSupport` in Dao implementation.

Comment: One more thing: could there be another application *using the same database* and exhausting your connection limit on DB side?

Comment: I am using AWS Database and there are about 5-6 database schemas but  this server instance is only pointing to one single database schema and that schema is only for this server..

Answer (score 1):

Update mysql global variables to increase connections.

```
set global max_connections=2000
```

Answer (score 1):

here if you are using like this.
app.jbdc.maxActive=2000
app.jdbc.maxWait =100

Then you can resolve this issue.

Basically this type of exception coming due to  unavailability of driver.

Answer (score 1):

From the stacktrace it appears that the dbcp connection pooling library is being used.

Your application is a client of the database, and it is configured to permit up to 200 (maxActive) connections.

My interpretation is that the database server is refusing connections before the 200 limit is reached.

You can either configure the server side to allow sufficient connections from your application, or reduce the number of connections that your application will try to allow.

Answer (score 1):

Try when creating a SQLMapClient give database properties with setting property Pool.MaxActiveConnections to some value.

```
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("Jdbc.Host", "localhost");
  props.put("Jdbc.Port", "3106");
  props.put("Jdbc.Database", "test");
  props.put("Jdbc.Username", "root");
  props.put("Jdbc.Password", "secret");
  props.put("Pool.MaxActiveConnections", "20");
  //timetowait in millliseconds
  props.put("Pool.TimeToWait", "20000");
  //sqlMapClientReader is reader of sqlmap-config.xml
  SqlMapClient sqlMap = 
    SqlMapClientBuilder.buildSQLMapClient(sqlMapClientReader, props);
```

or set it in your sqlmap-config.xml

```
<dataSource type="SIMPLE">
            <property name="JDBC.Driver" value="${driver}"/>
            <property name="JDBC.ConnectionURL" value="${url}"/>
            <property name="JDBC.Username" value="${username}"/>
            <property name="JDBC.Password" value="${password}"/>
            <property name="Pool.MaximumActiveConnections" value="${activeConns}"/>
            <property name="Pool.TimeToWait" value="${timeToWait}"/>
</datasource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't close the connection resource like conn.close() in your query method !

Comment: I am using iBatis which handles connection open and close automatically, we do not have to do anything to manually close the connection.